# Combine two columns into one column, and have values in new column correspond to unique combinations of values in adjacent columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes.

First dataframe:

```
#################################################

### create first data.frame
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 8))


### vector of column names
cols <- c("identifier1", "identifier2", "time", "lightsaber_length", "blaster_length")

### assign column names to df1
colnames(df1) <- cols

### generate random data for time column
tenths <- seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = .1)
sample_time <- sample(tenths, size = 8, replace = TRUE)

### generate random data for lightsaber_length and blaster_length columns
hundredths <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = .01)
sample_lightsaber <- sample(hundredths, size = 8, replace = TRUE)
sample_blaster <- sample(hundredths, size = 8, replace = TRUE)

### Assign column values
df1$identifier1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)
df1$identifier2 <- c("hello", "hello", "hello", "there", "there", "general", "general", "kenobi")
df1$time <- sample_time
df1$lightsaber_length <- sample_lightsaber
df1$blaster_length <- sample_blaster
```

[image: df1]

second dataframe:

```
### create second data.frame
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 8))

### vector of column names
cols <- c("study_id", "identifier1", "identifier2", "object")

### assign column names to df2
colnames(df2) <- cols

### create new study_id column, where study_id equals row number
df2$study_id <- 1:nrow(df2)

### move study_id column to front
df2 <- df2 %>% relocate(study_id, .before = identifier1)

### assign column values
df2$identifier1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
df2$identifier2 <- c("hello", "hello", "there", "there", "general", "general", "kenobi", "kenobi")
df2$object <- c("lightsaber", "blaster")
```

[image: df2]

I want a third dataframe, generated from wrangling df1 and df2, that combines 'lightsaber_length' and 'blaster_length' into one 'length' column. However, I want to retain which 'object' a 'length' value corresponds to by assigning the appropriate 'study_id' in the same row.

Each 'study_id' value represents a unique combination of 'identifier1', 'identifier2', and 'object', and does away with the need to have two separate length columns.

Desired output:

[image: df3]

As my actual data is larger and more varied, I would like a solution that is not unique to the small example I made here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and then do a join

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = ends_with("length"), names_to = c("object", ".value"),
      names_sep = "_") %>% 
    left_join(df2)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 16 x 6
   identifier1 identifier2  time object     length study_id
         <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>    <int>
 1           1 hello         4.5 lightsaber   0.28        1
 2           1 hello         4.5 blaster      0.92        2
 3           1 hello         1.7 lightsaber   0.42        1
 4           1 hello         1.7 blaster      0.57        2
 5           1 hello         8.5 lightsaber   0.55        1
 6           1 hello         8.5 blaster      0.88        2
 7           2 there         4.7 lightsaber   0.09        3
 8           2 there         4.7 blaster      0.37        4
 9           2 there         0.1 lightsaber   0.57        3
10           2 there         0.1 blaster      0.74        4
11           3 general       3.6 lightsaber   0.18        5
12           3 general       3.6 blaster      0.15        6
13           3 general       6.8 lightsaber   0.84        5
14           3 general       6.8 blaster      0.66        6
15           4 kenobi        1.2 lightsaber   0.76        7
16           4 kenobi        1.2 blaster      0.64        8
```